# why this Questions is showed in two way when you are reviewing?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

when you click on review tools you can see this answer :

[image]

and when you are reviewing low quality post you can see the same answer :

[image]

I think this is a double effort and should be eliminated.

but in the review tools (1) when you flag a question your **helpful flags** is increased and in the review pool (2) you **earn badges**.

any comment about this behaviour or reason to do in that way?

NOTE : if I'm remember well, this began when the review pool feature start.

[image]

Comment: Those are a lot of red circles.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug.

The *10k moderator tools* are not part of the review system at all, so there's no reason whether or not something appears there should be related to whether or not it appears in review.

Furthermore, they serve very different purposes:

- The Low Quality Posts review exists so people can:

  - recommend posts for deletion (or vote to delete them, if they have enough reputation).
  - indicate that posts are fine.
  - edit posts to improve them.
- The 10k mod tools exist so people can:

  - agree with existing flags and add weight to them by flagging (or, where applicable, by voting to close).
  - disagree with existing flags and dispute them by flagging as invalid.
  - (less frequently) flag for moderator attention to explain a special situation other than the above.

You cannot vote to delete from the 10k mod tools interface, and you cannot flag from the Low Quality Posts review queue. This is by design. (Though, under some circumstances, it makes sense to open up and flag a post that you find in the Low Quality Posts review queue.)